# Execute stored procedure only once but pass different parameter values 10 times

Tags: arrays, sql-server, t-sql

I want to execute a stored procedure only once but pass different parameter values every time from the temp table #tbl_schools. How can I accomplish this task?

```
create table #tbl_schools(id int not null)

insert into #tbl_schools(id) values (1)
insert into #tbl_schools(id) values (2)
insert into #tbl_schools(id) values (3)
insert into #tbl_schools(id) values (4)
insert into #tbl_schools(id) values (5)
insert into #tbl_schools(id) values (6)
insert into #tbl_schools(id) values (7)

select * from #tbl_schools nolock

go-----------

create proc sp_Prac @id int
as
print 'ID is: ' + cast(@id as varchar(10)) + char(10)

go-----------

exec sp_Prac @id = select id from #tbl_schools  -- This part errors out.
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Are you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Answer:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl_schools(id INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #tbl_schools(id) VALUES (5)
INSERT INTO #tbl_schools(id) VALUES (13)
INSERT INTO #tbl_schools(id) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO #tbl_schools(id) VALUES (7)
INSERT INTO #tbl_schools(id) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO #tbl_schools(id) VALUES (8)
INSERT INTO #tbl_schools(id) VALUES (4)

SELECT * FROM #tbl_schools NOLOCK

GO-----------

CREATE PROC sp_Prac @id INT
AS
PRINT 'ID is: ' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + CHAR(10)

GO-----------

DECLARE @MAX INT, @MIN INT, @CurValue INT
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)RN
INTO #MyTable
FROM #tbl_schools
SELECT @MAX=MAX(RN),@MIN=MIN(RN) FROM #MyTable

WHILE @MIN<=@MAX
BEGIN
SELECT @CurValue=ID FROM #MyTable WHERE RN=@MIN
EXEC sp_Prac @id = @CurValue
SET @MIN=@MIN+1
END

DROP TABLE #tbl_schools
DROP TABLE #MyTable
```

**Result:**

```
ID is: 1

ID is: 2

ID is: 4

ID is: 5

ID is: 7

ID is: 8

ID is: 13
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dinesh for your guidance. From now, I will take the sp_ naming convention into consideration. I believe I used a bad example in my previous example. What if I have a list of ids not sequentially ordered. They are a set of numbers and I want to read those numbers from the list one by one into my stored procedure parameter and execute my proc only once? Thank you!

Comment: @SashaJ, You are welcome. Can you please try my updated answer, hope it helps you.

Comment: You are welcome @SashaJ. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @SashaJ, If it works then accept the answer as correct, this may help someone.